# Python system argument reading '&'

Tags: python, bash, shell, command-line-arguments

I want to pass url to my python via the console and then do the appropriate tasks. many of the  links contain the character '&' in the link. python interprets that  as ending the argument this however is not what I want. here is a sample of the code

```
import sys

external_id = sys.argv[1].encode("utf-8")
print external_id
```

And when I run the following:

```
python graph.py 2%60&7
```

I get:

```
2%60
```

How do I make python interpret the '&' as nothing more than another character in the url?

Comment: Throw an escape character in front, ie. `\&`

Comment: Seems like this isn't a python issue as much as a terminal issue.

Comment: You probably missed the fact that your shell displayed somewhere that little error message: `bash: 7: command not found`. That was a big clue ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/86253):

> The `&` informs the shell to put the command in the background.

Python never receives that character because the shell takes care of it, thus this isn't an issue of Python. You can also wrap `2%60&7` with quotes to make it work

```
me@pc:~$ python3 script.py '2%60&7'
b'2%60&7'
```

Sometimes escaping `&` is a lot harder than doing this.

Answer (score 6):

This is not python, it's bash. You need to escape it:

```
python graph.py 2%60\&7
```